# Trouble in understanding and using setInterval() with .each()

Tags: jquery, timer, setinterval

What I'm tring to do here:

There are few elements I want to show 1 by 1 with time. So, I tried using following code:

```
/*Defining an object with selectors*/
var ticks_obj = {
    1: "#Pros1",
    2: "#Pros2",
    3: "#Pros3"
};

/*Using setinterval within loop with 1 sec gap*/
jQuery.each(ticks_obj, function(index, val){
       setInterval(function(){
            jQuery(val).show(500);
       }, 1000);
});
```

Trouble is:

`.show()` is taking place at once in all elements. Not one by one.

So, I changed the code and did:

```
/*Object Definition here*/

/*Using loop within setinterval*/
jQuery.setInterval(function(){
       jQuery.each(ticks_obj, function(index, val){    
           jQuery(val).show(500);
       });
 }, 1000);
```

This is showing no result.

I Can't understand it. Can anybody clarify it in bullet points in few words?

Also what could be easiest solution using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
jQuery.each(ticks_obj, function(index, val){
       setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery(val).show(500);
       }, index * 1000);
});
```

Comment: Although this works, I think OP would love having a small explanation ;)

Comment: Hi, it works. You changed 2nd param of `setInterval()` from _1000_ to _index * 1000_. Now it became a variable. Then it should work without `setInterval()` Can you tell a little more please?

Comment: @Nirjhar, no it will not work without setInterval how ever you should use setTimeout basically I only increased the interval between 2 calls

Comment: @Satpal yes I understand. Completely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you did

```
jQuery.each(ticks_obj, function(index, val){
       setInterval(function(){
            jQuery(val).show(500);
       }, 1000);
});
```

it iterated over the elements **really** fast and each respective interval executed withing *milliseconds* of the last interval. This is why they were shown at the same time.

You dont really need `setInterval` as you can just pass `duration` like you were doing with `.show()` and increment the `duration` with each iteration

```
var duration = 1500;
jQuery.each(ticks_obj, function(index, val){
      jQuery(val).show(duration);
      duration += 1500;
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/m7ew5mLv/)

Comment: The first part of your answer is correct, but your suggestion does not really answer the question: the OP is not looking to increase the duration for every element, but rather, show them one by one, delayed.

Comment: @LéoLam, I know, that is why in the second part, I increment duration. That is how it will show them delayed

Comment: @Nirjhar, it seems I misunderstood what you want. Dont you want to show the first element after 1500 sec, the second after 3000 sec,  and so forth?

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more precise. What I meant is that this only makes the show() longer, but does not delay it.

Comment: @AmmarCSE I see the point. My code wasn't working because  `setInterval()` was was within a loop and the loop got executed mainly. `setInterval()` had no significance there. Clear. Now, your suggested code is logical. But it's not working. "... show the first element after 1500 sec, the second after 3000 sec, and so forth? ..." Yes I want that, with smaller interval say 500, 1000, 1500 etc. But I really don't get why your code isn't working?

Comment: @AmmarCSE Yes it's working and it's great in my case too. But I have a note: if you notice carefully `show()` is delaying itself by time amount. Not the interval between 2 `show()` events are elongated. That's why I was using `setInterval()`, because I wanted to increase the interval, not the process of display, which should be fixed to 500 ms. :-)